# 'SavePoint' do not work in NPoco(Oracle) for separate execute statements

Tags: sql, oracle, npoco

I'm trying to use NPoco + Oracle + SavePoint. But when I'm trying to rollback savepoint, it throws exception.

Example:

```
NPoko.IDatabase db = new ...
db.Execute("SAVEPOINT ABC");
db.Execute("ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT ABC");
```

Exception:
"ORA-01086: savepoint 'ABC' never established in this session or is invalid"

I need to call 'savepoint' then call some other methods and then rollback or commit.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know NPoco , but could there be an autocommit setting?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, yes, it is. Thank you. I had to open transaction via some methods attributes like [Transaction]